# prototypeJS Ajax call vanishes

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

I've got a problem with an Ajax request in my web project. Most of the time it works just fine but sometimes there is simply no request from the client (it does not show in `wireshark`), FireBug just shows the request marked red.

Project looks like the following:

Java Backend with JSPs, Client is using the Firefox Browser

The request is done via `prototypejs` using the [Ajax Updater](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/Updater/index.html) function. I can debug the request preparation via `firebug` until the Ajax Update function fires the request but then no request is listed in my wireshark output (although all other request are listed just fine).

So I have a (sometimes) vanished Ajax request with no error and no clue where to look :( Any help would be much appreciated.

Request:

```
[...]/ajax/gruppe/loadTreeList.do?ajax=true&tstamp=645&context=GRUPPE&level=0&it‌​emid=0
```

RequestHeader:

```
Accept text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, /  
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate  
Accept-Language de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3  
Connection keep-alive  
Cookie JSESSIONID=326D8AEAAFD254760CEC8D050734807E  
Host localhost:8080  
Referer [...]/domain/druck/gruppe.do  
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0  
X-Prototype-Version 1.7.1 
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
```

There is no response.

Comment: Some code and additional info can help, can you post the red request on firebug?

Comment: Request- Responseparameters/values from firebug can be helpful